# cmake-gui: command not found

Tags: macos, cmake

I've installed cmake from https://cmake.org/download/ and followed the instructions in the readme to a T. Cmake has downloaded for me successfully, but when I run cmake-gui, I get a command not found error. I also can't find cmake in my applications folder (I'm using a mac).

How can I get cmake to run in it's gui version?

Comment: "I've installed cmake from https://cmake.org/download/ ..." - The page contains *several ways* for install CMake. Which **exact way** you followed, and which **exact steps** you performed for install CMake?

Comment: I installed cmake-3.12.0.tar.gz (the first link under "Unix/Linux Source") and followed the instructions in README.rst

Comment: You probably did not enable the GUI when building from source.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, I just had to download the file under "binary distributions"

Comment: I've installed binary distribution for mac (CMake 3.12.4) which is the latest in `brew` and still `command not found: cmake-gui`.